# How to draw an image, so that my image is used as a brush

Tags: python, tkinter, draw, tkinter-canvas

I created this little algorithm that is supposed to draw an image (imagine that my brush is an image) so that when I keep clicking I will draw the image, but as you can see if you test the code, it does not paint.

What it does is just moves the image across the `Canvas`.

Is there a way for the image to remain on the `Canvas`?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=800, height=400)
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
imagen = Image.open('C:/Users/Andres/Desktop/hola.png')
P_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)

def paint( event ):
    global w, P_img_crop
    #I get the mouse coordinates
    x, y = ( event.x - 1 ), ( event.y - 1 )
    #I open and draw the image
    img_crop = Image.open('C:/Users/Andres/Desktop/papa.png')
    P_img_crop = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_crop)
    w.create_image((x,y), anchor=NW, image=P_img_crop)

w.bind( "<B1-Motion>", paint )
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT
I did not know that the image that was drawn on the canvas, should be saved, so what I did is store the images in a matrix, which belongs to the canvas.
Here is the code, just in case ...

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=800, height=400)
w.dib = [{} for k in range(10000)]
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
puntero = 0

def paint( event ):
    global w, P_img_crop, puntero
    #I get the mouse coordinates
    x, y = ( event.x - 1 ), ( event.y - 1 )
    #I open and draw the image
    img_crop = Image.open('C:/Users/Andres/Documents/PROYECTOS INCONCLUSOS/PAINT MATEW PYTHON/hola.png')
    w.dib[puntero]['image'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_crop)
    w.create_image((x,y), anchor=NW, image=w.dib[puntero]['image'])
    puntero += 1
    if(puntero >=10000):
        puntero = 0

w.bind( "<B1-Motion>", paint )
mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do remove the image creation inside the `paint()` function. Then you will achieve what you want because otherwise it creates the image again and doesn't save a copy behind. In other words, when you move the brush, the previous image is garbage collected.

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=800, height=400)
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
img_crop = Image.open('yes.png')
P_img_crop = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_crop)
def paint(event):
    global P_img_crop
    #I get the mouse coordinates
    x, y = event.x - 1, event.y - 1
    #I open and draw the image
    w.create_image(x, y, image = P_img_crop)
    

w.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)
master.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works, but. Is there a way to create the image inside the function (not exactly create, let me explain)? What happens is the following. I have an image saved outside of my paint function, suppose my brush is a 50px square, what I need to do is that when I paint on the canvas, the image I have saved will be "rebuilding" on the canvas, for that I need I cut my image into a 50px square and to do that I need to be inside the function. Because the part of the box that I cut, depends on where the location of the mouse is. Is there a way to do it ???

Comment: @mrwringo Ok let me think.

Comment: @mrwringo, I made it so that you create the image inside the function, but you initialize it outside the function. That is the closest you can get...